# how to update parent table twice if child table return two same id of parent table in mysql using IN

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, sql-update

This is the query I'm using, it's working fine but the problem is if (select u.ChannelId from u) return twice the same id of a channelInfo, IN function only update ChannelInfo.Amount once, but it has to minus Amount twice.
For example, if (select u.ChannelId from u) return like this (3, 3), it has to minus ChannelInfo.Amount twice, but it's only minus it once.

How I can solve this problem, can anyone help me, please
ChannelInfo table has one to many relation with Reporting, so in Reporting table can have 2 or 3 ChannelInfo id

```
with u as (
      update "Reporting"
          set "Status" = 'run'
          where "Status" = 'a'
      RETURNING "ChannelId"
     )
update "ChannelInfo"
    set "Amount"= (CASE WHEN "Duration" = '60' THEN "Amount" - 12.25 ELSE "Amount" - 6.13 END)
     where "id" in (select u.ChannelId from u);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking for, but I think it is to subtract the count of the rows in `u` from the amount.  That is, the constant would be multiplied by a count.

You can use a join to get a count and use that for the calculation:

```
with u as (
      update "Reporting"
          set "Status" = 'run'
          where "Status" = 'a'
      RETURNING "ChannelId"
     )
update "ChannelInfo" ci
    set "Amount"= (CASE WHEN ci."Duration" = '60' THEN ci."Amount" - uc.cnt * 12.25 ELSE ci."Amount" - uc.cnt * 6.13 END)
    from (select u.ChannelId, count(*) as cnt
          from u
          group by u.ChannelId
         ) uc
     where ci."id" = uc.ChannelId;
```